# What, exactly, is a “poozer?”

Tags: dc, green-lantern

Kilowog, the drill sergeant for the Green Lanterns, often refers to others (friends and enemies alike) as “poozers.” Is this a reference to anything either in-universe or out-of-universe, or is this simply the alien version of the cliche drill sergeant calling people “maggots?”

*Or is Kilowog actually a heavily-accented space hipster that calls out posers throughout the universe?*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> "It was from Ermey that Kilowog learned the phrase "Poozer" for a "useless rookie", a phrase Kilowog would become famous for when he himself would train future Lanterns. "
>
> From: [Comic Vine Wiki](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/kilowog/4005-6952/)

So Poozer means useless rookie. It's just their terminology for it, not referencing anything specifically out of universe.